# CORS JSON php No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I don' get how do I fix this at all, I've been sitting there for hours and nothing.
[image: errors]

From my angular I use http.post like this:

```
function PostReview(JSONObject) {
    if(JSONObject!=null){
         $http({ 
             url: 'http://localhost:8000/creation',
             method: "POST",
             data: JSONObject,
             headers: { "Content-Type":  "application/json"} });

         }
    }
```

In php I try to get it like this:

```
public function created()
{
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $request = json_decode($json);
 var_dump($request);
// $email = $request->email;
//return response()->json($request);
}
```

I also have Cors class where I handled OPTIONS preflight problem. I tried adding headers there, but had no luck:

```
    class CorsMiddleware {
    protected $settings = [
                'origin' => '*',    // Wide Open!
                'allowMethods' => 'GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
                'allowHeaders' => 'Content-Type, Origin'];
    protected function setOrigin($req, $rsp)
    {
        $origin = $this->settings['origin'];
        if (is_callable($origin))
        {
            // Call origin callback with request origin
            $origin = call_user_func($origin, $req->header("Origin"));
        }
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
    }

    protected function setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp)
    {
        if (isset($this->settings->exposeHeaders))
        {
            $exposeHeaders = $this->settings->exposeHeaders;

            if (is_array($exposeHeaders))
            $exposeHeaders = implode(", ", $exposeHeaders);

            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', $exposeHeaders);
        }
    }
```

```
    protected function setMaxAge($req, $rsp)
    {
        if (isset($this->settings['maxAge']))
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', $this->settings['maxAge']);
    }

    protected function setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp)
    {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowCredentials']) && $this->settings['allowCredentials'] === True)
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    }

    protected function setAllowMethods($req, $rsp)
    {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowMethods']))
        {
            $allowMethods = $this->settings['allowMethods'];

            if (is_array($allowMethods))
            $allowMethods = implode(", ", $allowMethods);

            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $allowMethods);
        }
    }
```

```
    protected function setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp)
    {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowHeaders']))
        {
            $allowHeaders = $this->settings['allowHeaders'];

            if (is_array($allowHeaders))
            $allowHeaders = implode(", ", $allowHeaders);

        }
        else // Otherwise, use request headers
        {
            $allowHeaders = $req->header("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        }

        if (isset($allowHeaders))
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $allowHeaders);

    }

    protected function setCorsHeaders($req, $rsp)
    {
        // http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png
        // Pre-flight
        if ($req->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
        {
            $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
            $this->setMaxAge($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowMethods($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
            $this->setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
        }
    }
```

```
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = new Response("", 200);
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
        }

        $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Does anyone have Idea how to fix it? I tried multiple examples and nothing works for me.

---

I think I got it fixed after changing angular post method to this:

```
function PostReview(JSONObject) {
    if(JSONObject!=null){
         $http({ 
             url: 'http://localhost:8000/creation',
             method: "POST",
             data: JSONObject,
             headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;", "Accept": "application/json"} });

         }
    }
```

Now I don't get errors, and method is post, but postman is empty.[image]

Comment: You shared a screenshot with the response to the `OPTIONS` request, but what does the response look like for the actual `POST`? (It seems like that's the response that's missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.) Taking a look at that response may help determine where the issue lies.

Comment: @monikakalt After your edit you're still screenshoting only the `OPTIONS` request. We'll need to see a screenshot of the `POST` request for `/creation`

Comment: @ElliotB.  I made some fixes in order to get `POST` method

Answer (score 5):

You are most likely not setting your response headers correctly. Your screenshot indicates that the headers are set correctly in the `OPTIONS` reply, but the headers are likely different (and insufficient) for the `POST` reply.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 600');
```

`header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

However, it's apparent from your PHP code that you're working within the confines of an API framework and forcibly setting the headers with `header()` may not be best practice.

Comment: Could you possibly look at the second screenshot I added? I'm so lost I don't know which sided (angular or php) needs fix.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome do not allow CORS by default. I personnally use a addon to bypass this restriction : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi